# jtable dialog fields

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jtable

hello i need help to add some fields in the jquery jtable plugin dialog as hidden fields...

I'm using asp.net mvc and i need to add all fields that i need to be updated in db.If i don't put this fields on the screen database row will be updated whit null values, because mvc databinding system are not finding the fields on the post action they will be created whit null values...

So to avoid manual binding and because information in not sensitive i want to put all the fields in the form as hidden! I have saw that i can add visibility:'hidden' to the field definition but this is just hiding the field from the grid not from the update dialog...Can someone explain me how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to use `list: false`

```
Password: {
    title: 'User Password',
    type: 'password',
    list: false
},
```